# Why would I use a class variable (ex: static private int n) and then use a getter and a setter for it?

Tags: java, object

I was reading an example where someone created a class variable (ex: static private int num;), but then he used a getter and a setter for that variable.

If I want to be able to access that variable why would I make the variable static instead of just making it an instance variabe (ex: private int num;)

Comment: Is it those setter and getter static too?

Comment: Can you put exact code, please. It would be difficult and inappropriate to make guess on what you might have read.

Comment: If you have a `private` variable (`static` or not) you will not be able to access it **outside** of the class without proper getters and/or setters.

Answer (score 0):

The static keyword has nothing to do with access the variable outside the class, static is just a variable that is shared between all objects of that class.
setter/getter is necessary to access private variable from outside the class (either static/non-static).

Answer (score 0):

Considering you mean something as below:

```
public class AlainQuestion {

    private static int alainQuestionActivity;
    private int answererAnswerActivity;

    public static int getAlainQuestionActivity() {
        return alainQuestionActivity;
    }
    public static void setAlainQuestionActivity(int alainQuestionActivity) {
        AlainQuestion.alainQuestionActivity = alainQuestionActivity;
    }
    public int getAnswererAnswerActivity() {
        return answererAnswerActivity;
    }
    public void setAnswererAnswerActivity(int answererAnswerActivity) {
        this.answererAnswerActivity = answererAnswerActivity;
    }


}
```

In above, you would create a static (or class) variable so that all the objects of that class will have same copy of it and instance variable so that each object will have its own copy.

And to answer on why? - This is called as **information hiding or data encapsulation**. Read [Oracle docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) and can search many other good online articles.
You would need data encapsulation so that nobody can access or modify your variables or state without your permission. For example if you want to put some rules or checks in place before anybody can modify `alainQuestionActivity` then you can put in `setAlainQuestionActivity()`. If you had not encapsulated `alainQuestionActivity` then it would have not beenn possible.

- A variable is made static so that all objects of the class will have same copy of it.
- A variable is encapsulated using getter/setter so that no one modifies the variable just  like that, you can employ modification rules/checks inside your setter.

Hope this helps!